# How to use Selenium to Scrape the website id for each rows

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a Python scraping code to scrape the website id. It has 29 rows on the webpage with a unique id for each row.
Here is my code

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(web)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="caseCriteria_SearchCriteria"]').send_keys(keys)


input("Press Enter to continue...")


content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('k-detail-cell')

for c in content:
        grid = c.find_element_by_css_selector('.party-card')
        g = grid.get_attribute('id')
        print(g)
        
driver.close()
```

I was able to get the id from the first row but then it gave an error `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".party-card"} (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)`

I am wondering am I doing it correctly? I attached a screenshot of the page source as well. every row are identical for the `<div class='data-party-id' ....>`

[image]

That will be great if I have get some advice!

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet Here is the link: https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29
But you need to put in 'White, Jasmine' for the Search Criteria and bypass the reCAPTCHA manually. Then it will navigate to the web page that I want to scrape.

Comment: What input to insert into the search field?

Comment: @Prophet you can input 'White, Jasmine' for the search field

Comment: See if my answer works correct. The `grid` and `g` names here are not what you used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,  I will give you Selenium approach solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(web)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caseCriteria_SearchCriteria"]')))

#here you should pass the CAPTCHA....

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caseCriteria_SearchCriteria"]'))).send_keys(keys)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p//input[@id='btnSSSubmit']").click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-detail-cell .party-card")))
time.sleep(2)
grid = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".k-detail-cell .party-card")
for g in grid:
    actions.move_to_element(g).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(g.get_attribute('id'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but I am wondering what does ```actions.move_to_element``` does and need to ```time.sleep(0.5)```

Comment: It moves to that element, simulating mouse action + small delay to make sure the element reaches it final location before you access it. You can remove the delay and probably it still will work, but with it it will be more stable.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much. I am actually working on the whole code to scrape the web page. Do you mind if I contact you in other ways to help me with the scraping code? I really appreciate it!

Comment: I just added you!